# GNU memmem vs C strstr

Tags: c

Is there any use case that can be solved by memmem but not by strstr?
I was thinking of able to parse a string raw bytes (needle) inside a bigger string of raw bytes(haystack). Like trying to find a particular raw byte pattern inside a blob of raw bytes read from C's read function.

Comment: If your 'needle' isn't a real character string (i.e. may contain embedded zero bytes), then `strstr` won't work.

Comment: Yes, that is literally what it is for. You have answered your own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the case you mention: raw binary data.

This is because raw binary data may contain zeroes, which are interpreted and string terminator by `strstr`, making it ignore the rest of the haystack or needle.

Additionally, if the raw binary data contains no zero bytes, and you don't have a valid (inside the same array or buffer allocation) extra zero after the binary data, then `strstr` will happily go beyond the data and cause Undefined Behavior via buffer overflow.

---

Or, to the point: `strstr` can't be used if the data is not strings. `memmem` doesn't have this limitation.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to searching in non-string data, `memmem()` can be used to look for substrings in just a portion of a longer string, something `strstr()` can't do:

```c
char somestr[] = "a long string with the word apple";
// Look in just the 5th through 15 characters
// (Haystack must have at least 15 characters or else) 
char *loc = memmem(somestr + 4, 10, "pp", 2);
```

and if you already know the lengths of the strings, it *might* be faster than `strstr()` when used on the entire haystack string, but that depends a lot on the implementation and should be benchmarked.

Comment: (pendants: yes, `strstr()` *can* look in part of a string as long as it's from the nth character to the end of the string. It can't stop before the end though.)